# TTF_RenderText with integer

Tags: sdl

Is it posible to use the TTF_Render_TextSolid controlled with one integer? I try to use stringstreams like this:

```
stringstream  _minutes;
stringstream  _seconds;
stringstream  _miliseconds;

_minutes << minutes << ":";
_seconds << seconds << ":";
_miliseconds << miliseconds;
```

(the variable minutes, seconds and miliseconds was already scoped)

But when I compile this, compile well but then, I run and this says : core dumped. So the error is in the memory part. mmh what happens?

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something along the lines of:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << miliseconds;
const string str = ss.str();
SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(textFont, str.c_str(), textColor);
```

Should work without a problem.

Do not store the `const char*` that comes out of it though!  As soon as your `str` goes out of scope, your `const char*` won't be valid anymore.